# Rails access model attribute before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `notices` and `comments` on those notices. The comments are also of class notice. When a notice is submitted for creation, its `commentee_id` will be blank if it is an original notice. If the notice is a comment on another notice, its `commentee_id` will be the id of the notice it is commenting on.

notices_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  @notice = @character.notices.build(notice_params)
  if @notice.save
    .
    .
  end
end

def notice_params
  params.require(:notice).permit( :content, :picture, :latitude, :longitude,
                                  active_comment_relationship_attributes: [:commentee_id] )
end
```

notice.rb:

```
belongs_to :character

has_one  :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                       foreign_key: "commenter_id",
                                       dependent: :destroy
has_one  :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :active_comment_relationship

before_validation  :create_commentee

private

  def create_commentee
    if !commentee_id.blank?
      create_active_comment_relationship(commentee_id: :commentee_id)
    end
  end
```

The new notice model doesn't get successfully created. I get the error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `commentee_id' for #<Notice:0x0000010c3a4708>)
```

When `create_commentee` is called, the new `@notice` instance has been created in memory but not yet saved to the database (`create_commentee` is a `before_validation` callback). At this stage, how do you correctly access `commentee_id`?

Neither this (`!commentee_id.blank?`):

```
def create_commentee
  if !commentee_id.blank?
    create_active_comment_relationship(commentee_id: :commentee_id)
  end
end
```

nor this (`commentee_id` not `:commentee_id`):

```
def create_commentee
  if !commentee_id.blank?
    create_active_comment_relationship(commentee_id: commentee_id)
  end
end
```

makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is that you're doing this:

```
if !:commentee_id.blank?
```

...when you should be doing this:

```
if !commentee_id.blank?
```

`:commentee_id` is a symbol, which is like a special kind of string, and it will never be blank (well, unless it's `:""`). You want to call the `commentee_id` method, i.e. without `:`).

P.S. If you want to be slightly more idiomatic, I'd recommend this instead:

```
if commentee_id.present?
```

Comment: Thanks, I've experimented with your changes (see edit) but I still have the same problem.